# angularjs - POST uma array de objetos (dados JSON) para a página php

Tags: php, angularjs

```
$scope.informations = [
    {
        "name": "asd",
        "rg": "1123",
        "certificado": null,
        "sex": null,
        "date": null
    },
    {
        "name": "fsdf233412423",
        "rg": "123123",
        "certificado": null,
        "sex": null,
        "date": null
    },
    {
        "name": "d23423423423423423",
        "rg": "123123123123123123",
        "certificado": null,
        "sex": null,
        "date": null
    }
];


$scope.enviar = function(){
    var url = 'gerar-algo.php';
    var informations = $scope.informations;
    $http ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        params: {
            data: informations
        }
    }).then (function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
};
```

PHP

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

foreach($data as $valor){
    echo $valor;
}
```

Está retornando o erro:

> Undefined index: data

Comment: O seu erro é apresentado no lado do AngularJS ou do PHP?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade é apresentado no php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você comentou que o seu erro está no PHP, provavelmente é pelo meio de recepção dos dados.

Tente usar o seguinte:

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$data = json_decode(json_encode($post),true);
```

Veja se isso resolve o seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o $http.post() e veja o retorno, lembre-se de instanciar um callback de erro na sua promise, para certificar-se de que o problema não é a nível de serviço, no seu caso, no PHP.

```
// Exemplo 
$http.post(url, {data: $scope.informations})
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```